# How to permanently delete a taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, database, taxonomy, mysql

I want to delete a taxonomy (both form wordpress and database) created long time ago and now no more used.
How to do it? I found this function but I think it will delete all my taxonomies... and I don't know how to choos only 1 taxonomy. Could you please help me? Thanks

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-load.php");
$results= $wpdb->get_results("select * from {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy where `taxonomy` LIKE  'post_tag'",ARRAY_A );
foreach ($results as $row){     
    $wpdb->query("delete from {$wpdb->prefix}terms where `term_id` =  '".$row['term_id']."'") ;
    $wpdb->query("delete from {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships where `term_taxonomy_id` =  '".$row['term_taxonomy_id']."'");    
}
$wpdb->query("delete from {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy where `taxonomy` LIKE  'post_tag'");

$wpdb->query("delete from {$wpdb->prefix}icl_translations where `element_type` LIKE  'tax_post_tag'");    
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function [wp_delete_term](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_term)

```
$todelete = array('one','two','three');

foreach ( $todelete as $slug ) {
  $term = get_term_by('slug', $slug, 'post_tag');
  if ( ! is_wp_error($term) && ! empty($term) )
      wp_delete_term( $term->term_id, 'post_tag');
}
```